# How to do mixed sampling in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, mcmc, tensorflow-probability

I am implementing a complex sampling algorithm using TensorFlow Probability's MCMC package. Let's say I am using Gibbs sampling for one component, Hamiltonian Monte Carlo for another, and finally Random Walk Metropolis. For example, suppose we have a joint probability,

> `p(X|a, b)p(b|c, d)p(c)p(d)p(a)`.

My custom sampling iteration is roughly:

```
def one_iteration():
   # Sampling `a`: 
   # part of joint density: p(X|a, b)p(a)
   # ...using some custom Gibbs sampler

   # Sampling `b`:
   # part of joint density: p(X|a, b)p(b|c, d)

   def log_prob(b):
      return p(X|a, b).log_prob() + p(b|c, d).log_prob(b)

   hmc = tfp.mcmc.HamiltonianMonteCarlo(
      log_prob, step_size=0.1, num_leapfrog_steps=3)
   samples, is_accepted = tfp.mcmc.sample_chain(
      num_results=1,
      num_burnin_steps=0,
      current_state=b,
      kernel=hmc)

   # Sampling `c`:
   # part of joint density: p(b|c, d)p(c)

   def log_prob(c):
      return p(b|c, d).log_prob() + p(c).log_prob(c)

   rwm = tfp.mcmc.RandomWalkMetropolis(log_prob)
   samples, is_accepted = tfp.mcmc.sample_chain(
      num_results=1,
      num_burnin_steps=0,
      current_state=c,
      kernel=rwm)
```

And then running this with:

```
for i in range(T):
   one_iteration()
```

Is this the correct method of mixed sampling? i.e. calling `sample_chain` each iteration for each component sampling algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda possible.  See this PR for a discussion of Metropolis within Gibbs.  Votes for the PR willraise the popularity of MwG and hopefully get it implemented.

https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/pull/1233